# Problem rosmake piano of mit-ros-pkg

Tags: ros, rosmake, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having problem rosmake the piano package in mit-ros-pkg.  The following is the error:

```
fatal error: SFML/Audio.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I had tried rosdep install piano, and it gave an error that it couldn't find

```
E: Unable to locate package libsfml-audio1.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libsfml-audio1.5'
```

I tried edit the rosdep.yaml in piano folder to change to libsfml-audio1.6, however rosdep keeps saying:

```
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
#Packages ['libsfml-audio1.5', 'libsfml-dev']
sudo apt-get install libsfml-audio1.5 libsfml-dev
}}}
```

Does anyone know where do rosdep obtain the above info.  It doesn't seem to refer to the rosdep.yaml in the package folder.  I checked the mainfest.xml and only refer to libsfml as rosdep.

I tried manually

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-audio1.6
```

The apt installed without problem.  However, rosmake piano continues to give the error:

```
fatal error: SFML/Audio.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Hope to get help here to fix the above problem.  I am on ros-electric on Ubuntu 11.10.

**UPDATE:**

@AzuriViolin  Many thanks for the ans.  I do not know why I couldn't reply (comment) directly in your ans.

Indeed, I assumed the only failure was on libsfml-audio but rosdep didn't install libsfml-dev.  So, I should:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev libsfml-audio1.6
```

The libsfml-dev provides the header files (developmental files) and so I got through the error of missing Audio.hpp.  As you encountered, the next error is the missing linkage to sfml-system in CMakeLists.txt.  It was resolved by:

```
roscd piano
gedit CMakeLists.txt
```

scroll to the bottom, and add sfml-system (few lines repeated):

```
rosbuild_add_executable(testsound src/exaudio.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testsound sfml-audio sfml-system)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29195/problem-rosmake-piano-of-mit-ros-pkg/) by [owh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1754/owh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the first problem.
the rosdep information comes from mit-ros-pkg/kinect_utils/rosdep.yaml file.

try add

oneiric:
apt:
packages: [ libsfml-dev libsfml-audio1.6 ]

in this rosdep.yaml file and you'll be fine.

After these steps, rosmake have found SFML/Audio.app, but there's new problem:

```
  /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/testsound.dir/src/exaudio.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sf::Sleep(float)'
  /usr/bin/ld: note: 'sf::Sleep(float)' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libsfml-system.so.1.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
  /usr/lib/libsfml-system.so.1.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

Originally posted by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) with karma: 67 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0